# modulus operator objective not working?

Tags: objective-c, c, ios4

% operator isn;t working in objective. I am doing simple seconds to minute:second conversion. the modulus operator isn't working it is giving me error "Invalid operands to binary %" what does that mean and what can I do to fix this.

thanks
TC

Comment: Perhaps show your inputs and your expected output. Also: I'm removing the C# tag...

Comment: can you please post some code..How can we tell what you are doing wrong without seeing the code..

Comment: Maybe it's not C#/C/whatever but is your code instead.

Comment: [First rule of programming: It's always your fault](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html) - please post your code so we can explain what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modulas operator only works for integers..Check whether your operands are floats..If they are floats or doubles, you can use [fmodf](http://www.codecogs.com/reference/c/math.h/fmod.php) instead..

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're probably trying to use `%` on a floating point operand, but `%` only works for integer types.